react-helmet-async SPA meta description not workingwhen app deployed
I'm using react-helmet-async to manage my web pages meta tags like title, description and keywords, when I inspect head tags I can see the react-helmet meta tags there with the attribute data-rh= true. However, when I deploy my app, the title meta tag works but the description (which is supposed to appear under the page name when searching the website on google) doesn't appear, is that because of client-side rendering, how to fix it without the need for server-side rendering ?
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";

return (
<main>
...
        <Helmet>
          <title>
            {lang === "en"
              ? "Bushnaq Group - Home"
              : "مجموعة بشناق - الصفحة الرئيسية"}
          </title>
          <meta
            name="description"
            content="some long description"
          ></meta>
          <meta
            name="keywords"
            content="Medical Center, Healthcare, Bushnaq Medical Center, Bushnaq Healthcare"
          ></meta>
        </Helmet>
</main>

)


